# Get width and height of the imageView after resizing using matrix

Tags: android

I want to get the width and height of the scaled imageView using this code that I got from the internet:

```
public class MultiTouch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

// these matrices will be used to move and zoom image
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
// we can be in one of these 3 states
private static final int NONE = 0;
private static final int DRAG = 1;
private static final int ZOOM = 2;
private int mode = NONE;
// remember some things for zooming
private PointF start = new PointF();
private PointF mid = new PointF();
private float oldDist = 1f;
private float d = 0f;
private float newRot = 0f;
private float[] lastEvent = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // handle touch events here
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            d = rotation(event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
                if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 3) {
                    newRot = rotation(event);
                    float r = newRot - d;
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float tx = values[2];
                    float ty = values[5];
                    float sx = values[0];
                    float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                    float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                    matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Determine the space between the first two fingers
 */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/**
 * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
 */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

/**
 * Calculate the degree to be rotated by.
 *
 * @param event
 * @return Degrees
 */
private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
    double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
    double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
}
```

}

My problem is if my original imageview is smaller than the scaled image, the image is showing but with the original size of my imageview. This is the part where the image is zooming:

```
                 if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
```

I want also to resize the container of my imageview.

This is the actual what is happening. the left image is the original, and the right side image is the actual result. I want the imageview container will be the same size of the scaled image.

[image]

Comment: Did you fix height and width of your imageview in layout?

Comment: yes by default the size of my imageview is 100x100

Answer (score 1):

you can get scaleFactor from your matrix by calling

```
float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
yourMatrix.getValues(matrixValues);
float scaleX = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
float scaleY = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
```

and then multiplying your main width and height by appropriate values

Answer (score 0):

Use `WrapContent` for both `Height` and `Width` of your `ImageView`